# Remove duplication elements in the list Haskell

Tags: haskell

My list is a [[String]] and it looks like [["A1","A2","A3"],["A1","A2","B1"],["A1","A2","B2"].....]

my codes is shown below

```
List = [[x,y,z] | x <- l1, y<- l2, z <- l3]
            where l1 = ["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3","D1","D2","D3"];
                          l2 = ....;
                          l3 = ....

compareTo :: [String] -> [String] -> Bool
compareTo x y
            |length (intersect x y) == length x     =True
            |otherwise                              =False 

removeDuplication :: [[String]] -> [[String]]
removeDuplication (x:xs) = nubBy compareTo (x:xs)
```

In this case, the order of elements has not taken into consideration, which measn ["A1", "A2", "A3"] and ["A2", "A3", "A1"] are duplications.

I want to use 'nubBy' and 'compareTo' functions to build up my removeDuplication function, and I'm not sure how to compare an element to all other elements in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to generate lists that are permutations of all Strings in l1. So maybe you don't need nub and compareTo.

```
list = [[x,y,z] | (x:xs) <- tails l1, (y:ys) <- tails xs, z <- ys]
  where l1 = ["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3","D1","D2","D3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You already finished all the bits and pieces to solve your problem.

You just have to compose the final line:

```
removeDuplication = nubBy compareTo
```

After fixing the remaining typos everything should work fine.

Comment: Just find out anything I want to avoid in the list which is the repetition of same elment inside [String]. For example, ["A1","A1","A2"] should also be avoided. All element in the [String] should also be distinct. I add 'l2' and 'l3' in my definition of 'List'. Is that the right way to solve this problem, and how should I define 'l2' and 'l3'